# How do you execute a SHELL script in multiple directories without having to generate a run script

Tags: shell

If I have the following file directory

```
/home/aero/airplane/case1
/home/aero/airplane/case2
..
/home/aero/airplane/casex (you get the point there could be many cases)
```

I have a shell script called runscript.sh (at the same level of all the cases) that performs some simple commands. I don't want to "cd" into each directory manually to then run the shell script. Is there a way to execute the shell script on all case directories that contains the name "case" by typing something along the lines of:

```
runscript.sh /case*
```

I know I can generate another script that could do this but I'm wondering if there's a way to run a script on multiple directories using a simple command?

Your help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to execute `runscript.sh` in the subdir itself, you want to find something for avoiding the lines

```
cd case1 && runscript.sh && cd ..
cd case2 && runscript.sh && cd ..
```

Here runscript.sh can return false and your `cd ..` can get you to wrong places.
You can avoid this by running everything in a subshell.
Test this with the runscript.sh script replaced by `pwd`.

```
(cd case1 && pwd)
(cd case2 && pwd)
```

Now wrap this up in a command finding all dir's starting with "case".

```
find case* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "{}"; pwd' \;
```

When you are happy with the result, fill in your script

```
find case* -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "{}"; ../runscript.sh' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for` loop. In this example you need to run the command from /home/aero/airplane/.

```
for dir in `ls -ad case*`; do runscript.sh $dir/; done
```

- `ls -ad case*`: list only directories starting with "case".

Comment: This didn't seem to work. My runscript.sh calls a python script which is supposed to modify a data file in the case directory but I get an error message saying the data file doesn't exist. The data file exists in that directory. There is nothing wrong with my rundcript.sh because if I "cd" into the case directory and then execute my script everything works.