# Create script taking output from another

Tags: bash, playlist

Basically I want to have a (generated) playlist in every folder containing music, sorted in order and has the same name as the folder.

I have a script that takes the information from music files and creates a playlist in a specific format.

1) I can run the script on single folder by

```
$ ./playlist.sh ~/Path/To/Music > output.xwaxpls
```

2) Put the playlist in a way that increases numerically (all my music is formatted `%track% - %artist% - %title%`)

```
$ sort -o output.xwaxpls output.xwaxpls
```

3) Change the name of output.xwaxpls to parent directory name

Unable to get this far yet.

Obviously I would love a script that would do all this.

I'm trying to learn and do each step one at a time but sadly I'm falling at the first hurdle. I can't even work out how to run the playlist.sh on all subdirectories. It's putting me off as I'm stuck before I can try the other two.

I would love some help....

Edit:

Another few hours and I'm getting somewhere !!

```
`#!/bin/sh

curdir=$(pwd)
for folder in ~/Music/*; do 
  [ -d "$folder" ] && cd "$folder" && ~/Desktop/./playlist.sh "$folder" > "$folder".xwaxpls && sort -o "$folder".xwaxpls "$folder".xwaxpls
done
```

`
This creates the playlists that I want, in the format that I want.......but the playlists are saved in ~/Music, not in the folder that contain the files.

I have tried to change the `~/Desktop/./playlist.sh "$folder" > "$folder".xwaxpls` part to `~/Desktop/./playlist.sh "$folder" > "$folder"/"$folder".xwaxpls` but an error is kicked out saying `cannot create /home/user/Music/Singles`//`home/user/Music/Singles.xwaxpls: Directory nonexistent.`

I have also tried to add `&& mv $playlist.xwaxpls $playlist/$playlist.xwaxpls` which results in the same `//` error.

The `//` I understand, as I am forcing a double path but why is the xwaxpls file not written to the `$folder` in the first place ? I presume it's because I have specified the `~/Music/*` in the for line ?

Comment: When I understand your hurdle correctly, you have an issue like https://stackoverflow.com/q/42682171/3220113. Please look there and update your question when you need something else.

Comment: Added && mv "$folder".xwaxpls "$folder" to the last line. I get the output that i want but it doesn't look right ?

Comment: I don't understand your `sort` command. The question is changing after each edit, perhaps try to make a new simple question and remove this one. You can give a newline after each `&&` and take a look at `echo "${playlist##*/}"`.
And consider removing the spaces from the filename.

Comment: I was updating my "script" as I discovered a way of doing each step, hence why the question changed slightly. I thought I was doing the right thing by doing it that way. I stumbled across the sort command and it worked when I tried it in that layout. I then tried to incorporate it in the script. Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it out tomorrow and see if I can understand what's doing what. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like

```
#!/bin/bash

for folder in ~/Music/*; do 
  [ -d "$folder" ] || continue
  cd "$folder" || continue
  ~/Desktop/playlist.sh "$folder" | sort -n > "$folder"/"${folder##*/}".xwaxpls 
done
```

Remember that you do not try `sort -o file file`, most unix commands don't like to write to an output file that is input at the same time.