# I want a for loop script to do some commands in every numbered subdirectory (1-400)

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am looking for "for loop" to run multiple script in each direcorty and save the output in the same directory

```
#!/bin/bash


for dir in /home/Desktop/4Testing/batch_2019-05-16/*     # inside batch_2019-05-16 there are 400 folders"
do
    dir=${dir%*/}      # remove the trailing "/"
echo "$1" *.pcap > 12.txt   # print everything after the final "/"
tshark -r *.pcap -T fields -e frame.time -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e frame.len -e _ws.col.src.prt -e _ws.col.dst.prt -E separator=, > home.csv      
cat home.txt 12.txt > Final.csv
done
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683508/3220113 how you can perform a set of commands in different subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can run into trouble if you directory names have spaces/weird characters or are files!  Much better to store your processing in a function/script that takes the directory name as a parameter and use `find`, something like:

```
find /home/Desktop/4Testing/batch_2019-05-16 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec <script_name> {} \;
```